# Group elements by nested field

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, method-reference

I have the following domain classes:

```
public class Task {
    private Project project;
}
```

```
public class Project{
    private int id;
}
```

And I have a list of tasks called `tasks`.

I would like to group `Task` objects by project's ids. The resulting type of the

I tried the code shown below. But it doesn't group objects by ids, but rather groups based on whether the key is the same object or not. I found duplicates, I tried to get rid of them, but I couldn't make it work.

```
tasks.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(task::getProject));
```

I want something like that

```
tasks.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(task::getProject::getId));
```

But unfortunately, I couldn't do that.

Comment: I think you would be able to achieve this without the shorthad notation. Like: `.groupingBy((T) -> T.getProject().getId())`

Comment: Use a simple lambda expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@n247s* has pointed out in the comments, the syntax of the Method reference you're using is **incorrect** - you can't chain method reference ([*for more details, refer to the official tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)).

The *keyExtractor* `Function` you need can be expressed only using a Lambda expression because in order to create a Method reference to an [instance method of a **Particular Object**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#object) you need to have a **reference** to it, you don't have it (it's not possible in this case).

Here's the only option:

```
task -> task.getProject().getId()
```

It would be possible to create a Method reference of this type using a method of the nested object if you had a reference to the enclosing object stored somewhere. For instance, like that:

```
Task foo = new Task();
Function<Task, Integer> taskToId = foo.getProject()::getId;
```

But since you're dialing with a stream element, it not feasible.

Comment: If i go this way it return map (project_id,task) but i want  (project,task) how can i achieve that ?

Comment: @SametDAĞ Then use `groupingBy(task::getProject)` like in your first code-snippet. It would give you a map `Map<Project,List<Task>>`.  If you need a map of type `Map<Project,Task>` then you need to use a different collector - `toMap()`.

Comment: but it grouping by project objects . i want to group by project ids and package them as project

Comment: @SametDAĞ `group by project ids and package them as project` - OK, `id` property is unique? If not, how to deal with duplicates?

Comment: yes ids are unique

Comment: @SametDAĞ If `id` property is unique, then you need to [override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java) in the Project class based on it. And you'll be able to get the result you need with `groupingBy(task::getProject)`. Remember as a rule of thumb: always `equals/hashCode` of your custom objects that are interned to be used as a Key in a `HashMap`, or stored in a `HashSet`.

Comment: @SametDAĞ Since `id` is unique - the correct way to establish the identity of the `Project` instances is implement `equals/hashCode` based on it.